# Buttons not showing up in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Making an app, and none of the buttons are showing up! Tried running on different phones. Googled around, and got nothing! Please help! If you need any more details, please let me know!

Snippet of code from activity with no buttons:

```
   <android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
    android:text="Text2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="244dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
    android:text="Text3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="145dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:text="Text4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="Text5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:text="Text1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use RelativeLayout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pasted your code directly into a new project and it works fine. Make sure that you're wrapping your components in another layout. Here is what I wrapped your XML with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.test.MainActivity">
<!-- The rest of your code goes here -->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like on my tablet:
[image]

Comment: Also, Matt is correct. You don't need the android.support.constraint.Guideline component at all for your layout to render properly.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `android.support.constraint.Guideline`, when you should be using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`.

Just change that and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
    android:text="Text2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="244dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
    android:text="Text3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="145dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:text="Text4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="Text5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:text="Text1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```